# bind data to ng-model that has parent key

Tags: angularjs, bind

this is my form in view:

```
<form name="myform" ng-submit="formSubmit(myform)" novalidate>
   <input type="text" name="finalBouquet" ng-model="form.data">
</form>
```

I want to bind data to "form.data" by this code but is doesn`t work:

```
$scope.form.data = "my text";
```

how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

do this

```
$scope.form = {data : "my text" };
```

Answer (score 0):

First Define :

```
           $scope.form ={};
```

then

```
           $scope.form.data = "my text";
```